# Empty form input is always valid, BindingResult.hasErrors is always false, even if the variables are marked with an @Size and @NotEmpty annotation

Tags: java, html, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I want validate input in form, and then if input is empty, show error message next to input field. The problem is that everytime I submit empty form, BindingResult.hasErrors() is false and processForm() method return name of confirmation page. I am using Hibernate Validator 6.1.3 and running application on Tomcat 9. I am learning from web course and same code works for lecturer but not for me.

I have customer-form.jsp file:

```
   <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
   //...
   <form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="customer">
     First name: <form:input path="firstName" />
     <br><br>
     Last name (*): <form:input path="lastName" />
     <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error" />
     <br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form:form>
```

I have methods in CustomerController:

```
@RequestMapping("/processForm")
public String processForm(
        @ModelAttribute("customer") @Valid Customer theCustomer,
        BindingResult theBindingResult) {
    if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()) return "customer-form";
    return "customer-confirmation";
}



@RequestMapping("/showForm")
public String showForm(Model theModel) {
    theModel.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
    return "customer-form";
}
```

and set annotations in Customer class:

```
 @Size(min=1, message="is required")
 @NotEmpty
 private String lastName;
```

I am using: Spring MVC-5.2.3.RELEASE & IntelliJ IDEA 2020
     
 **libs:** 
 jstl-1.22 
               javax.servlet-api-4.0.12 
            javax.annotation-api-1.3.22 
 hibernate-validator:6.1.3.Final

Comment: Add your controller class declaration - CustomerController. I want to see class annotations used.

Comment: @Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {//...}